# Appstore release affecting TestFlight testers?

Tags: ios, testing, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

Say for example internal and external testers under `TestFlight` are testing the application. Then a live `Appstore` release that was uploaded previously gets approved. Will the current testers get the new app update which will override the current test build?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Testing
>   Once you accept your invitation, you’ll be able to download a beta version of the app you’ve been invited to test. If you already have the live app installed on your device, the beta version of the app will replace the live version. When you’ve downloaded the beta app, you’ll see an orange dot next to its name that identifies it as a beta. TestFlight will notify you each time a new build is available and provide instructions on where to focus. You can easily offer feedback by tapping the Provide Feedback button in the App Details view in TestFlight. An email automatically opens with pertinent app and device details, and you can add additional details and screenshots.
>
> The beta period lasts for 60 days, starting on the day it is released
>   to testers. In TestFlight, the number of days remaining appears below
>   the Open button for each app.
>
> If a beta app has In-App Purchases, you do not have to purchase them,
>   as In-App Purchases made with beta builds are free within the context
>   of the beta version.

Quote from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

Tester won't get notified whether the original app is approved by Apple or not. If the app is approved, then user have to download app via App Store. But if tester downloads app from App Store, then it's gonna override the test version.

Answer (score 2):

Apple developer site says

> When the app becomes Ready for Sale in the App Store, testing automatically stops on earlier builds, and you will be unable to view or test them.

Refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html)

Comment: will the current testers get a notification saying that the live version is ready and current test has been cancelled?

Comment: Can I able to upload testing builds for the testers after the live.

Answer (score 1):

I think the tester will get an email saying the app has been updated and approved. Since the normal upload will be notified by an email, but haven't tried it ,

Answer (score 1):

TestFlight testers will get notification by email and after app live beta version of app will be unavailable and when they update their app they get live update app.